# How can I remove the extra space in cards bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-cards

[image: click to see image]

So I've been losing my head trying to figure this out. I can't seem to make the cards horizontally centered inside this section and when I checked inspect elements, it turns out the cards are occupying some extra space which isn't really padding or margin. Badly need help on this one. I simply used bootstrap grid and the goal is to get the cards equally centered horizontally.

```css
#products
{
    @include sectionDefaultValues();
    #products-txt-cont
    {
        background-color: $siteColor;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    #products-txt
    {
        color: white;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="products">
  <div id="products-txt-cont">
    <h2 id="products-txt">PRODUCTS AND SERVICES</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalone">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalone">
            <div class="modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                          </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col col-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaltwo">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modaltwo">
            <div class="modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-4">
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalthree">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
          <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalthree">
            <div class="modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Put 'no-gutters' class https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Comment: tried it but still no cigar, the width of the card element itself is bigger than what its supposed to have, tried modifying the width but no effect as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FIGURED IT OUT LOL, just had to add `mx-auto` class to the cards